# 5V relay (jqc-3ff-s-z)

Tags: gpio

Is it possible to use an external adapter for the 5V, so connecting the + from the adapter to VCC of the relay and the - of the adapter to GND of the relay. Then IN to GPIO27. Setting this low will trigger the relay?
I tried, but it seems not to work. 
I ask this, because I want to use a NO/NC magnetic door switch.
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Yvonne

Comment: Insufficient information to make any meaningful answer

Comment: @Lodv, Ah let me see.  I googled and found the following: "Using single 5V relay (jqc-3ff-s-z) - Safety Advice Required":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73311/using-single-5v-relay-jqc-3ff-s-z-safety-advice-required.

Comment: Yes, provided you connect the Pi ground to the external power supply ground (as well as the relay ground).

Comment: @Lodv, The asker I referred above asks advice for Hesai (TongLing jqc-3ff-s-z) relay, but his connection diagram shows another relay Keyes SR1y (KY019) using Songle relay.  Please confirm which relay you are using, or give us the web link to your relay..

Comment: I think that is the solution sharing ground.
I found this article:
https://majenko.co.uk/blog/importance-sharing-grounds
Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I made a sketch, but I don't know how I can attach it to this comment. I'm still confused. How can I show it in my jpeg file to you?

Answer (score 1):

jqc-3ff-s-z is NOT a relay, it's a "relay module"!

The relay module has a driver circuit included on the modules board.

And yes it is possible to use a external power source to the relay module (jqc-3ff-s-z).

Just remember to:

- Connect GND on the relay module to both the Raspberry Pi and the external power source.
- Connect VCC only to the external power source.
- Connect IN to only the Raspberry Pi.