# How voltage tolerant is the RPi 3 A+ micro-B USB power connection?

Tags: pi-3, power, power-supply, usb-power

I've been reading about power supply requirements for RPi and want to learn more about the practical limits in addition to the design limits. **What is the power protection circuit (if any) on the micro-USB port, what is the maximum voltage it will tolerate?**

I have set up a test power supply (using a bench power supply, 7.5A (18AWG) leads to a micro-USB headshell). So I can see the relatively exact supply details. I've measured the voltage at the RPi micro-USB, and noted a 0.1V cable loss at 5.5V supply, so I believe my test cable can carry sufficient power.

While exploring the under-power situations described in a lot of articles on the web, I've varied the input voltage from 5V to 5.5V (which seems stable), and briefly risked up to 6V without frying the RPi. I am interested to know at what point I can expect smoke.

Comment: If you're interested in powering the Pi safely, (rather than blowing it up), then [this math](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118647/33476) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pi 3 is protected by the [SMBJ5.0A](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88392/smbj.pdf) over-voltage suppressor, which has a breakdown voltage between 6.4 and 7.1V. So above 7.1V you are guaranteed to trigger the over-voltage protection.

If the protection works as designed, you'll see no smoke: the polyfuse will limit the current to a safe value. However, 7.1V is above the rated maximum voltage of 5V components on the Pi, so there's still a good chance those ICs will blow up before the voltage suppressor has a chance to act.

Comment: `there's still a good chance those ICs will blow up before the voltage suppressor has a chance to act`... That would be my definition of a poor design.

Comment: @Seamus It is, and the never-ending stream of questions which all boil down to "bad power supply" and "current limit of USB ports" is the proof. I really miss Banana Pi which never had power problems, allowed to connect a battery directly to the PCB, and exposed the PSU and battery voltages and currents via `/sys/class/power_supply`.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but don't they still make the BPis? I don't know much about them - are they supported by the maker?

Comment: @Seamus They do, and they ever release new boards. Software-wise  the manufacturer support was poor even for the first BPis, and I doubt that has changed. You'd be stuck with Wheezy on the Banana Pi 1 unless you learn how to install Debian. And they lost the competitive edge too: the original Banana Pi was several times faster than the original RPi (and only 1.5 times more expensive), but the latest boards are more or less on-par with Pi 4, while they still cost more. For example, Banana Pi M3 costs $150-200 where I live.

Comment: Ouch! Somewhat similar to my BeagleBone experience.

Answer (score 1):

The Pi is rated at 5.0 ± 0.25V.
The PMIC (on modern Pi) has a MAXIMUM input of 5.5V - exceed this at your peril.

The "protection" circuitry consists of a combination of polyfuse, ideal diode and surge limiting diode, which varies on model (consult schematics for detail). The Pi3A+ has no ideal diode.

[Schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/) for most models are available.

See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)